# How to improve performance when using custom fonts in Android EditText?

Tags: android, performance, fonts, textview, android-edittext

I'm customising a `TextView` in Android with a .ttf font, using:

```
Typeface handType = Typeface.createFromAsset ( getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/JOURNAL.TTF");
```

Problem is that when it enters into edit mode, characters don't appear on the screen immediately as with the default inbuilt font, but they take some time to render, short but enough to make it feel sluggish.

Is there any technique (cache, etc) that would help me to get the fonts rendered instantaneously?

Also noticed the delay varies  from font to font and seems to get worst with font complexity

Comment: while on create you will declare edittext right at that time itself change the custom font to the edittext.

Comment: Is it emulator or real phone? Real phones are faster.

Comment: Real, is a Google Nexus S. Pretty seamless in most apps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Performance issue on custom font TextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338016/performance-issue-on-custom-font-textview)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a factory. It's really better because we don't allocate fonts each time.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.Log;

public class FontFactory {
private static FontFactory instance;
private HashMap<String, Typeface> fontMap = new HashMap<String, Typeface>();
private Context context;

private FontFactory(Context context) {
    this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
}

public static FontFactory getInstance(Context context) {
    if(instance == null){
        return instance = new FontFactory(context);
    } else {
        return instance;
    }
}

public Typeface getFont(String font) {
    Typeface typeface = fontMap.get(font);
    if (typeface == null) {
        try {
            typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getResources().getAssets(), "fonts/" + font);
            fontMap.put(font, typeface);  
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("FontFactory", "Could not get typeface: " + e.getMessage() + " with name: " + font);
            return null;
        }

    }
    return typeface;
}
```

}

Gist: https://gist.github.com/odemolliens/4d5ff5630b6317397956