# Performance issue on custom font TextView

Tags: android, performance, textview

I have a custom TextView, with a personalized font attribute:

```
public class TextViewPlus extends TextView {
    private static final String TAG = "TextViewPlus";
    public TextViewPlus(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public TextViewPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        // This is called all the time I scroll my ListView
        // and it make it very slow. 
        super(context, attrs);
        setCustomFont(context, attrs);
    }
    public TextViewPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setCustomFont(context, attrs);
    }
    private void setCustomFont(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray a = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TextViewPlus);
        String customFont = a.getString(R.styleable.TextViewPlus_customFont);
        setCustomFont(ctx, customFont);
        a.recycle();
    }
    public boolean setCustomFont(Context ctx, String asset) {
        Typeface tf = null;
        try {
            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), asset);  
            setTypeface(tf); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not get typeface: "+e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I'm using it in my XML files with the attribute **customFont="ArialRounded.ttf"**, and it is working quite well.

I'm using this TextViewPlus in a ListView, populated with an ArrayAdapter.

```
TextViewPlus dataText = (TextViewPlus) itemView.findViewById(R.id.data_text);
dataText.setText("My data String");
```

My problem is that the performance, when I'm scrolling the ListView, are terrible! Very slow and full of lags. The TextViewPlus constructor n°2 it's called all the time i scroll the list.

If I change TextViewPlus in a normal TextView, and use **dataText.setTypeface(myFont)**, everything is smood and is working well.

How can I use my TextViewPlus without performance issue?

Comment: Have you tried caching your `Typeface` somewhere, so it isn't getting created each time?

Comment: I do now. I tried the solution of Praful Bhatnagar and it is working very well

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Why don't you keep the created `typface` object in memory so that you don't create every time the text view is getting created.

Following is a sample class that creates and cache the typeface object:

```
public class TypeFaceProvider {

    public static final String TYPEFACE_FOLDER = "fonts";
    public static final String TYPEFACE_EXTENSION = ".ttf";

    private static Hashtable<String, Typeface> sTypeFaces = new Hashtable<String, Typeface>(
        4);

    public static Typeface getTypeFace(Context context, String fileName) {
    Typeface tempTypeface = sTypeFaces.get(fileName);

    if (tempTypeface == null) {
        String fontPath = new StringBuilder(TYPEFACE_FOLDER).append('/').append(fileName).append(TYPEFACE_EXTENSION).toString();
        tempTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), fontPath);
        sTypeFaces.put(fileName, tempTypeface);
    }

    return tempTypeface;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm glad it worked but the caching shouldn't give you any performance boost in case you implemented your ListView adapter correctly. That is, the views (including the textviews) are reused. If they are reused properly then no .ttf file should be loaded anymore during scrolling.

Comment: @Zsolt Safrany sorry but that's not quite right. It will affect page loading time if not affected scrolling. Assume that you have 7 visible items of 3 textviews each, then the typeface will be loaded 21 times from the assets, which is terrible.

Comment: How to use this class?

Comment: @PrafulBhatnagar Thanks a lot, bro. I was using custom font in `RecyclerView` and `Viewpager`. One item of  `RecyclerView` has 2 fonts and `ViewPager` tab title has two fonts(One for selected and another for disabled) and I was thinking why my app is slow while scrolling and swiping and today I realized it and started searching for solution and ended up here.