# Create Custom Font which one is better

Tags: android, android-fonts

I am new in android and I want use my custom font for my app. I wrote 2 ways creating custom font. Could you tell me guys which one is better and faster.
first way is using singleton class second way is create my own textview.

with singleton

```
public class FontFactory {
    private  static FontFactory instance;
    private HashMap<String, Typeface> fontMap = new HashMap<String, Typeface>();

    private FontFactory() {
    }

    public static FontFactory getInstance() {
        if (instance == null){
            instance = new FontFactory();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public Typeface getFont(DefaultActivity pActivity,String font) {
        Typeface typeface = fontMap.get(font);
        if (typeface == null) {
            typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(pActivity.getResources().getAssets(), "fonts/" + font);
            fontMap.put(font, typeface);
        }
        return typeface;
    }
}
```

with own textview

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {
    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setFonts(context,attrs);
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setFonts(context,attrs);
    }

    private void setFonts(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyTextView_customFont);
        String ttfName = a.getString(R.styleable.MyTextView_customFont_ttf_name);

        setCustomTypeFace(context, ttfName);
    }

    public void setCustomTypeFace(Context context, String ttfName) {
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/MuseoSansCyrl_"+ttfName+".otf");
        setTypeface(font);
    }
    @Override
    public void setTypeface(Typeface tf) {

        super.setTypeface(tf);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom textview approach, you are creating the Typeface object every time you create a CustomTextView (or change its typeface), while your factory would keep the already loaded ones around in memory and re-use them.

The approach with a custom text view may work fine in some instances, but if you suddenly need to create a lot of them (or change the typeface on a lot of them), it might noticably slow down your performance as in [this question with a scrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15338166/151682).

I'd choose the singleton.